# Get an XML response in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, vb.net, web-services

I have a homebrew vb.net webservice (hobby) running on a machine on my network, I'd like to call the service for an XML response in android programmatically, but I'm a real novice and no luck.

The service is located at `http://192.168.1.100/service` with arguments of `r` as response type, e.g. `...service?r=xml` will return XML, parameters can be passed via `...&arg1=parameterX` and so on.

Could anyone point me in the direction of some code that would accomplish calling and then processing the XML response? I've been struggling for about two to three hours with this, tried many many tutorials most of which did nothing, with the remainder crashing the app.

Comment: hi try the following link https://github.com/PareshMayani/Android-SAX-Parsing it is example of xml parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are 2 steps involved in performing the task that you have specified:

> 1.To fetch the xml from the server
>
> 2.To parse the fetched xml (in
>       the 1st step) for getting the necessary data from your xml

To get the xml data by using Http, follow this post:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Here is a very basic tutorial on how to parse an xml file:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

**Entire solution to your quetion you might find here:**
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html#consume

---

P.S.: If you are new to android development then just go through the sample codes that is there on the official android developers' [website](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: @rabbitt i hope that you found a solution to your problem :)

Comment: I'm still unable to get it to work, I know it's a lot to ask, but is there a more idiot proof/comprehensive solution somewhere?

Comment: @rabbitt  did you try the code that is given in the 3rd link??

Comment: It confused me, I tried but it seemed a lot of it was irrelevant and I couldn't make it work. Sorry,

Comment: @rabbitt I don't understand what was irrelevant. I guess it was the perfect solution to your query

Comment: Sorry, it just seemed I didn't need a lot of that code. I re-read my question and realised I hadn't framed my requirements properly. The most significant thing I need to accomplish is to pass parameters to a webservice within the URL, and I just can't seem to get that to happen. Application crashes every time. The XML would be a bonus, but right now is little more than gimmicky.

Comment: @rabbitt **referring to the code of the 3rd link**, instead of passing the `URL` string....you can always make another string by appending your parameters to the `URL` string to make another string(or the other option is use instance of `StringBuilder` class to append multiple parameters one by one) and then use it to query the server..